# Count ocurrences in an array bash

Tags: linux, bash, associative-array

Im trying to count ocurrences in an array using an associative array

```
 #!/bin/bash

arr=@{}
arr2=(A B B C D A B)

for i in "${arr2[@]}"; do  #Run trough array

    if [[ -v arr[$i] ]];  #Check if key exists at associative array
    then
        arr[$i]=arr[$i]+1 #Increment value
    else
        arr+=([$i]=1)     #Create key/value pair
    fi

done

for i in ${!arr[*]} #Run trough associative array
do
  echo $i ${arr[*]}
done
```

I get the output:  0 arr[B]+1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is wrong in more places. This is a correct one:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A arr
arr2=(A B B C D A B)

for i in "${arr2[@]}"; do  #Run trough array

    if [[ -v arr[$i] ]];  #Check if key exists at associative array
    then
        arr[$i]=$((${arr[$i]}+1)) #Increment value
    else
        arr[$i]=1     #Create key/value pair
    fi
done

for i in ${!arr[@]} #Run trough associative array
do
  echo $i ${arr[$i]}
done
```

and the output is:

```
A 2
B 3
C 1
D 1
```